# Change String in List<String> based on another String same List Java

Tags: java, string, list, dictionary, collections

I've got a List containing String like those :

```
device0001;sale;2013-01-01 00:00:00;30.45
device0001;sale;2013-01-02 00:00:00;41.02
device0001;sale;2013-01-03 00:00:00;30.45
...
device0001;saleCode;2013-01-01 00:00:00;10
device0001;saleCode;2013-01-02 00:00:00;55
device0001;saleCode;2013-01-03 00:00:00;55
```

Multiple Device, multiple CodeName and Date by Device. I'd like to map the Value of the saleCode to the sale CodeName.
Example of what I'd like in the end :

```
device0001;10;2013-01-01 00:00:00;30.45
device0001;55;2013-01-02 00:00:00;41.02
device0001;55;2013-01-03 00:00:00;30.45
```

The saleCode String may or may not be kept, it doesn't matter.

I've made it work with 2 for loop and ifs, but it was way too long to process.

I thought about building something like this :

```
Map<String(device), Map<DateTime, Map<String(element), String(value)>>>

forEach device
    forEach datetime
        element (Codename substring) and replace by element (Value substring)
```

I'm pretty sure there must be a better and/or elegant way to do this.

EDIT - Since it doesn't seem so clear why I'm trying to do, here is the code with for and if (which is way too slow) :

```
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (line.split(SEPARATOR)[4].equals("sale")) {
            for (String codeLine : lines) {
                if (codeLine.split(SEPARATOR)[5].equals(line.split(SEPARATOR)[5]) &&        
                    codeLine.split(SEPARATOR)[1].equals(line.split(SEPARATOR)[1])&& 
                    codeLine.split(SEPARATOR)[4].equals("saleCode")) {

                    line = line.replaceAll("sale", codeLine.split(SEPARATOR)[7]); 
                }
            }
         }
    }
```

The index doesn't fit with my string's examples only because there are other non important fields, but index [1] is the device number, [5] the date. [4] is the type (sale, saleCode) and [7] the value.

EDIT #2

I've improved the speed like so :

```
MultiKeyMap<String, String> multiKeyMap = new MultiKeyMap<>();

for (String line : lines) {
    if (line.split(SEPARATOR)[4].equals("saleCode")) {
        String device = line.split(SEPARATOR)[1];
        String date = line.split(SEPARATOR)[5];
        String value = line.split(SEPARATOR)[7];

        multiKeyMap.put(device, date, value);
     }
}

for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    String code = lines.get(i).split(SEPARATOR)[4];

    if (code.equals("sale")) {
        String device = lines.get(i).split(SEPARATOR)[1];
        String date = lines.get(i).split(SEPARATOR)[5];
        String newline = lines.get(i).replaceAll("sale", multiKeyMap.get(device, date));

        lines.set(i, newline);
     }
}
```

I'll go for that for the moment, but always open for advices.

Comment: Instead of using lists of strings, parse into a list of objects (each of which as 4 fields).

Comment: Do you only need to read-in one list, and write out the other? Do you plan on processing it any further, like taking a decision based on the saleCode? Depending on the context and how you are intending to use that, you are going to get very different answers (List of objects vs regex search and replace).

Comment: @JoD.Yes, only need read-in the list and write the other. I'll do processing later on but it doesn't have anything to do with this mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you don't need to build any maps etc.
You have a list of strings with that format.
Just go over each string and use a regular expression to replace/update each string.

**Update:**
Your code is slow because you are processing the list over and over for each string.

1. Create a hashmap based on device id.
2. Go over the strings in `lines` one by one.
3. Check if the string exists on hashmap.
    If it does not exist then then check which type of string it is and apply a proper regex for replacement. Add the string to the hashmap
    If it does exist then update the string via a regex using the newly encountered string.
   When you are done the hashmap will have the strings replaced.

**Note:** I am mentioning regexes because it seems you have a specific format and it might be written easily and efficiently that way. If you can't use regexes e.g you are not familiar with them follow the approach of parsing it character by character as you are doing. Still it will be better as you process the list once

Comment: No, this isn't immediately clear but I think he does need maps. The first output string gets the `10` part from the first `saleCode` string, and it gets `30.45` from the first `sale` string. It matches those two input strings because they both have `2013-01-01 00:00:00`. (I don't know whether it's safe to assume that you can do it just by matching the first `sale` string with the first `saleCode` string, the second `sale` string with the second `saleCode` string, etc.)

Comment: @DavidKnipe You are right, the matching needs to be done Both with the device number AND the date.